# Canvas ActualWidth and ActualHeight passed into ViewModel in MVVM way

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Recently I've encountered a problem with a seemingly easy taks: I wanted to use Mode=OneWayToSource to push Width and Height parameters of a canvas into a ViewModel in one application that I work on. Turns out Mode=OneWayToSource does not work for that and according to Microsoft it is a feature of WPF that was intended. Ok, sure.

Anyway, I've been scratching my head about this for some time thinking about how to do this the best ( that is the shortest and the least messy) way while adhering to the MVVM principle. I've figured the following:

```
/// <summary>
/// Sends graph dimensions to <see cref="GraphViewModel"/>
/// </summary>
public class SendGraphDimensionsToViewModelProperty : BaseAttachedProperty<SendGraphDimensionsToViewModelProperty, bool>
{
    public override void OnValueChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!(sender is Canvas canvas))
            return;

        canvas.SizeChanged += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (canvas.DataContext is GraphViewModel graph)
            {
                graph.Width = canvas.ActualWidth;
                graph.Height = canvas.ActualHeight;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Then i just attach the property to a canvas with DataContext of GraphViewModel instance:

```
local:SendGraphDimensionsToViewModelProperty.Value="True"
```

**This works as intended.** Basically the attached property's value changes from null to true on load which triggers the SizeChanged event that monitors the ActualHeight and ActualWidth of the Canvas.

My question is: Would you suggest any improvements to my code (related to possible memory leaks for instance and such)? I would just like to "MinMax" this while learning something new. I am a junior dev and I cannot really consult this with someone IRL, as nobody I know does MVVM. I am trying to write everything in a modular fashion, meaning I want to write it once and then just subsequently copy it when I need it again to speed up the rate at which I can develop apps.

Looking forward to your suggestions.

Comment: If you use the Canvas inside e.g. a UserControl you could add a new DP to that control and return ActualWidth and ActualHeight of the Canvas from its property.

Comment: @Lennart I've been thinking about that, but right now I am not using the Canvas inside a UserControl (it is inside of a Page). I've not been able to figure out a way to use such DP in that scenario.

Comment: _"how to do this the best ( that is the shortest and the least messy) way while adhering to the MVVM principle"_. The answer is to not do what you are intending to do at all. If you you want to implement strict MVVM then this is not an option. I don't know exactly what you are doing, but if `GraphViewModel` is meant to hold graph related data, then the question must be: how does height and width of a rendered object belongs to the information contained by a graph? A graph has no dimensions. Dimensions are only important for the rendering.

Comment: Rendering or visualizing data is the responsibility of the view. View model and model are only responsible for data. As suggested, you should implement this properties as `DependencyProperty` on the control that hosts the `Canvas`.

Comment: To comment on your posted code: don't use events to propagate data. Use data binding: define the required  properties on the hosting `UserControl` and bind the `Canvas`  to them. If you think you must do this using events, then at least use thw `WeakEventManager` inside your `UserControl`.

Comment: _" I am trying to write everything in a modular fashion, meaning I want to write it once and then just subsequently copy it when I need it again"_ If you want to reuse code then move it into a class. The when you want to use this code again you simply reference the class. If you do care about quality, then this class has a set of unit tests. Copying code will introduce bugs. You'd introduce duplicate code, maybe even spread across applications. Modifying the code in one place e.g., to fix a bug, requires to modify all copies too. And then don't forget a single one. Always reuse classes.

Comment: @BionicCode GraphViewModel is there to generate graph axes and to transform the width and height of the canvas from values in pixels which are difficult to work with to values in “graphed units” ... eg: if a canvas is 100px wide then 0px would be year 2010 for instance and 100px year 2020. Every 10 pixels would then represent 1 year steps in “graphed units” ... it is easier to work with the graph this way. I will try to implement it through DPs. Thank you.

Comment: A collection of reusable classes are called library. Create your library, composed of well tested and documented classes.

Comment: No. You would use a converter or data point mapper to convert graph data to layout pixels. View model doesn't care about layout pixels.#

Comment: If you are trying to plot a Cartesian chart or similar, then the view model should only contain the data points e.g. `Point` or some custom data model  class. Now your control is responsible to plot this data points correctly, based on rendering details like available space, scaling, zoom etc. Your view can use helpers to mapp the data points to the actual drawn axis. But this is solely view logic. Your view model only holds a collection of data point objects, with their associated meta data.

Answer (score 2):

My solution for this issue was a group of attached properties, which can be applied to any FrameworkElement instance.

```
public static class perSizeBindingHelper
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ActiveProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "Active",
        typeof(bool),
        typeof(perSizeBindingHelper),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(OnActiveChanged));

    public static bool GetActive(FrameworkElement frameworkElement)
    {
        return (bool) frameworkElement.GetValue(ActiveProperty);
    }

    public static void SetActive(FrameworkElement frameworkElement, bool active)
    {
        frameworkElement.SetValue(ActiveProperty, active);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty BoundActualWidthProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "BoundActualWidth",
        typeof(double),
        typeof(perSizeBindingHelper));

    public static double GetBoundActualWidth(FrameworkElement frameworkElement)
    {
        return (double) frameworkElement.GetValue(BoundActualWidthProperty);
    }

    public static void SetBoundActualWidth(FrameworkElement frameworkElement, double width)
    {
        frameworkElement.SetValue(BoundActualWidthProperty, width);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty BoundActualHeightProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "BoundActualHeight",
        typeof(double),
        typeof(perSizeBindingHelper));

    public static double GetBoundActualHeight(FrameworkElement frameworkElement)
    {
        return (double) frameworkElement.GetValue(BoundActualHeightProperty);
    }

    public static void SetBoundActualHeight(FrameworkElement frameworkElement, double height)
    {
        frameworkElement.SetValue(BoundActualHeightProperty, height);
    }

    private static void OnActiveChanged(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!(dependencyObject is FrameworkElement frameworkElement))
        {
            return;
        }

        if ((bool) e.NewValue)
        {
            frameworkElement.SizeChanged += OnFrameworkElementSizeChanged;
            UpdateObservedSizesForFrameworkElement(frameworkElement);
        }
        else
        {
            frameworkElement.SizeChanged -= OnFrameworkElementSizeChanged;
        }
    }

    private static void OnFrameworkElementSizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is FrameworkElement frameworkElement)
        {
            UpdateObservedSizesForFrameworkElement(frameworkElement);
        }
    }

    private static void UpdateObservedSizesForFrameworkElement(FrameworkElement frameworkElement)
    {
        frameworkElement.SetCurrentValue(BoundActualWidthProperty, frameworkElement.ActualWidth);
        frameworkElement.SetCurrentValue(BoundActualHeightProperty, frameworkElement.ActualHeight);
    }
}
```

Usage is ...

```
<Grid ...
    vhelp:perSizeBindingHelper.Active="True"
    vhelp:perSizeBindingHelper.BoundActualHeight="{Binding GridHeight, Mode=OneWayToSource}"
    vhelp:perSizeBindingHelper.BoundActualWidth="{Binding GridWidth, Mode=OneWayToSource}">
```